# Attempting to create two different modals but the two buttons bring up the same modal. Can someone help me?

Tags: javascript

I have a fiddle here with the code I am trying to write. As the title suggests, I want to (even 3 eventually) modals that fade in when a button is clicked. Right now both buttons bring up the same original modal. I'm sure its an easy answer but can someone point me where I am wrong?

Here is the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/cqfa4uh6/2/

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<button id="myBtn2">Open Modal2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal2">
   <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content2">
    <div class="modal-header2">
      <span class="close2">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-body2">
      <p>Testing Some other text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Testing Some more other text...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal, .modal2 {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content, .modal-content2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close, .close2 {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close2:hover,
.clos2:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-body, .modal-body2 { 
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}


/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Javascript

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's wrong in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqfa4uh6/2/) code:

1. In the HTML, the `div`s aren't closed correctly for `modal 1`, so modal 2 is "held" within modal 1.
2. In The JS, the first set of click events for the modal1 is being overridden by the second set of event listener code for the modal2. Also, the two event listeners attached to `window` need to be combined into one single handler. Otherwise, the second one would override the first one, since there's only one handler for `onclick`. Use `addEventListener` to bind multiple event handlers to a particular event on a particular DOM element. Here's the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) for EventListener interface.

Here's the fixed [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqfa4uh6/24/).

Comment: Thanks so much. Such simple mistakes, can't believe I missed them. Thank you.  While I have you, would you know the syntax to change the close function so that you can click anywhere in the window to close the modal? Right now its set to close when clicking outside the modal, but I want to set it to inside and outside the modal.

Comment: Here's one way to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/cqfa4uh6/35/. Notice the `stopPropagation` added to the button event handlers. This prevents the click event (on the buttons) from bubbling to the `window` and triggering the event handler set on that (which hides the modal). Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers in the second half of the code are all referencing `modal` instead of `modal2`. Fix with the below:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. However, once fixing that mistake it seems theres still another. Now the second button doesn't work and the first button opens both modals one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

check the next:

```
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

with btn2 you should display modal2 not modal